# Reproduce a colorbar with auto-rescaling between min & max value to use entire spectrum

Tags: matlab, matplotlib

I am new to matlab and stackexchange too.
I wish to reproduce a colorbar for my own work (guess it was made using tecplot) preferably in MATLAB or python (matplotlib).

Here's an example of what I want to reproduce:

http://iopscience.iop.org/0963-0252/23/1/015007/downloadHRFigure/figure/psst484284fig14

My idea is to have a script which can be run on any x-y-z type of data such that this colorbar is applied in a way that all the colors are used (presume it will be some kind of rescaling?)

This colorbar does not need to display the actual values but just min and max will suffice.

Many thanks for all your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for matlab. Since you do not say anything about recreating the colormap I assume that you know how to do that. However, if not, try the colormap editor.

```
surf(peaks(30));
colormapeditor;
```

Where peaks is a function creating some good demo data. The colormap can the be obtained from the figure. About your problem: Normally the colormap is automatically scaled to use the full spectrum of your colormap. If this for some reason does not work, set the `CLim` property to the range of your spectrum. That can for example be the maximum and minimum for your data or some other suitable range.

Good luck!

Comment: It was the colormapeditor I had to use to get something like the original plot.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/93zrubdrcixlq7v/untitled.jpg?dl=0

Now how do I set the colorbar to display only 'min' and 'max' instead of the actual scale as in the original plot?

Comment: @jackryan I think that you can set the `Ticks` (which is a property of the `ColorBar`) to max and min of the data, I guess that you may want to round the values to nearest "easy to interpret value" as well, but that is you choice.

Comment: been 3 days trying [min,max];Thanks 4 any help.
rho_w = 999.1;
rho_s = 1376;
mu    = 1.109e-3;
chi   = 0.51; 
L     = 0.003;
T     = 289.15;
V     = 18.02e-6;
R     = 8.314;
k     = 5.1e-21;
%k     = 3.1e-21;
D0    = R*T*k / (mu*V);
theta0 = 0.12;
thetae = 0.61;
tscale= D0/L^2;

E = R*T/V;
[cc,pp]=meshgrid(0.5:0.01:1.5, 0.1:0.01:0.9);
psps = -E .*[log(1-pp) + pp + cc.*pp];
dpsps = E .*[(2.*(pp.^2))./(1-pp)].*[(cc-0.5)-(cc.*pp)];
figure
contourf(cc,pp,psps,64,'LineStyle','none');
colormap;
axis square;
xlabel('\chi','FontSize',18);
c=colorbar('horiz','location','southoutside');
xlabel(c,'\psi')

Comment: @jackryan Soory for the late answer. You have not yet set the `Ticks` property of the colorbar. Try to add this line in the end: `set(c,'Ticks',[min(psps(:)), max(psps(:))-0.025*max(psps(:))]);`. The part `0.025*max(psps(:))]` was added since the `max(psps(:))` got out of range somehow. I am not sure why, but it seems to work when removing the last 2.5 percent. However, it may have to do with the range being to large. The variables `m` and `u` was not set in the example so I set these values to 1. You may get other values.

Comment: Dear Patrik, Indeed I am late; my apologies. Thanks for all the help; I was finally able to make it using this...
c = colorbar('horiz','location','southoutside','XTickLabel',{'min','','','max'});